# angular infinite-scroll error when changing ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

My angular app uses ngInfiniteScroll

```
angular.module('myApp',['ui.router', 'infinite-scroll'])
```

I load a partial into a ui-view directive. The partial has infinite-scroll set up on a ul element. This works fine and responds to data returned from an $http call invoked in a search service.

(This is a part of the Jade template partial)

```
div#results-container
  div.intermediatediv
    ul(
       infinite-scroll="homeCtrl.searchMore()"
       infinite-scroll-parent = "true"
       infinite-scroll-distance="0"
       infinite-scroll-container="'#results-container'")
       li(ng-repeat="lot in homeCtrl.searchResults", ng-bind-html="lot.lotDescription")
```

Using a ui-sref anchor on this page and with ui-router I change the template part in the ui-view directive element.

```
a(ui-sref="home.<routeName>") <A link text>
```

The new template part does load and displays OK but there is no infinite-scroll directive within the markup.

So, I get this error in the Firebug console:

'elem.document is undefined'

Any thoughts about why this happens?

Thanks